# How can I create a function that takes Sets as input?

Tags: functions, function-construction

The function takes a list of integers as an input and spits out a vector of length `l` that contains 1 at the positions that are specified in the list, else zeros.

Let’s say that

```
l=5; A:={1,4};
```

then

```
f[A]={1,0,0,1,0}

A:={1,2,3}
OGV[A,l_]:=Table[If[Element[i,A], a[i]=1,a[i]=0],{i,1,l}]
```

It gives me an error:

> SetDelayed::write: Tag List in
> {a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],<<90>>}[{1,2,3}]
> is Protected.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l = 5; a = {1, 4};

SparseArray[# -> 1 & /@ a, l] // Normal
(* {1, 0, 0, 1, 0} *)
```

Comment: Could you please explain how the function you made works? I have trouble understanding the & and @/ symbol

Answer (score 4):

From your description: The function takes a list of integers as an input and spits out a vector of length l, that contains 1 at the positions that are specified in the list, else zeros.

Below a is the list of indices, len is the total length of the vector, and v is the desired output vector.

```
a = {1, 3, 7};
len = 10;
v = ConstantArray[0, len];
v[[a]] = 1;

v
{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ReplacePart` seems pretty relevant to your task. But it takes position specifications. I'm going to add the length as an argument to make this more extensible.

```
func[len_Integer, positions : {___List}] := ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, len], positions -> 1]
```

You could choose to either prepare your arguments before using `func` or to overload `func` to handle indices. In the latter case, you would add this definition:

```
func[len_Integer, indices : {__Integer}] := func[len, List /@ indices]
```

So, we have

```
func[5, {1, 2}]
(* {1, 1, 0, 0, 0} *)

func[6, {{3}, {1}}]
(* {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0} *)

func[3, {9}]
(* {0, 0, 0} *)
```

You could also use `SparseArray` where `positions` are assigned to 1.

```
func[len_Integer, positions : {___List}] := Normal[SparseArray[positions -> 1, len]]
```

But you'll need to do something else to handle invalid positions.